# How do I convert a file from a pandas dataframe read_csv into a numpy array with commas in between and 'numpy.ndarray' type?

Tags: arrays, list, numpy

When I use 'to_numpy' or 'values' it converts it to the non-comma separated array. They are both 'numpy.ndarray' type. How to get the second type of array? The top one is the first type of array and the bottom is the second type of array.

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 0. ]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2 0. ]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 0. ]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 0. ]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2 0. ]
 [5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 0. ]
 [4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3 0. ]
 [5.  3.4 1.5 0.2 0. ]
 [4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2 0. ]
 [4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1 0. ]


array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
       [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
       [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
       [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
       [5. , 3.4, 1.5, 0.2],
```

Comment: What is reason for this? 2d numpy array is displayed without `,`.

Comment: Or need `arr.tolist()` ?

Comment: Those are the same array, one is the `str` format, the other the `repr`.  Try `print(repr(arr))`.

Comment: hpaulj, that seems to work. However, it needs to be in 'numpy.ndarray' type and this is 'str' type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a small array:

```
In [167]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                               
In [168]: type(arr)                                                                      
Out[168]: numpy.ndarray
```

display it with `str`:

```
In [169]: print(str(arr))                                                                
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

display it with 'repr':

```
In [170]: print(repr(arr))                                                               
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

The object being display is of type `str`:

```
In [171]: type(repr(arr))                                                                
Out[171]: str

In [172]: repr(arr)                                                                      
Out[172]: 'array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],\n       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],\n       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])'
```

Don't confuse the Python object, such as `ndarray` with its string representation.